# .net 4.0 creating a MemoryMappedFile with global context throws exception

Tags: c#, ipc, shared-memory

I want to create a global MemoryMappedFile in C# 4.0 using following call:

```
string MemoryMappedFileName = "Global\\20E9C857-C944-4C35-B937-A5941034D073";
ioBuffer = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(MemoryMappedFileName, totalIoBufferSize);
```

This always throws following exception "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied."
If I remove the "Global\" identifier from the memorymapped filename it works but I need a memory mapped file existing accross terminal sessions.

ps: It works if I run as administrator...

thanks,
Christoph

Comment: I think you've found your answer. Privileges.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I also want to write automated integration tests. They fail if they are run under normal privileges. That's why I want to know if its possible to create global shared memory under normal privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Check your local security policy for "Create global object".  Grant the specific trusted user account the privilege.  Be mindful of security issues, so don't grant it to a group.